# How to send a request xml to a server and get a response xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, request

I need to send a request xml to a server apache, and get a xml response, end after that to parse him. I need this for a log in.

In this way I create the request xml:

```
public Document createRequest(String un, String pass, String an) 
{
    Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();

    Element root = document.addElement( "request" );
    Element header = root.addElement( "Header" );
    Element content = root.addElement( "Content" );
    Element username = content.addElement( "username" )
            .addText(un);
    Element accountnumber = content.addElement( "accountnumber" )
            .addText(an);
    Element password = content.addElement( "password" )
            .addText(pass);

    return document;
}
```

Those are the three xml (request/response valid/response error):
The request I need to create (the creation is above), and the response I need to parse so I could the **Session ID**.

```
MobileUserLogin

Request

<Request>
    <Header>
    </Header>
<Content>
<UserName>John</UserName>
<AccountNumber>21945574396</AccountNumber>
<Password>xyz</Password>
</Content>
</Request>

Response
Valid

<Response>
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Content>
        <SessionID>24865725834</SessionID>
    </Content>
</Response>

Error

<Response>
    <Header>
        <Error>serialized error object</Error>
    </Header>
    <Content>
    </Content>
</Response>
```

UPDATE:
I need help so I could send a xml request to a server and get the xml response to parse him to get the **Session ID**.

In conclusion i need help with the code, I'am new in xml.

Comment: Please clarify the actual question.

Comment: I still don't get your question. Do you want to send a request without headers with the parameters specified in the XML? Then why bother to create the XML at all? And do you want to send a GET or a POST request (or PUT, DELETE or HEAD, but these are less common).